# Where to put Constants.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, configuration-files

I'm a newbie to Swift and iOS programming in general, and I'm currently getting my hands dirty building a Swift app. I have encountered this problem of where to put the `Constants.swift` file (which basically stores the constants used by the app), and the confusion is mainly caused by the MVC logic. I have two options that I deem somewhat reasonable.

1. Put `Constants.swift` outside of the MVC framework, so that it does not belong to any particular party. Rationale: this way it could be conveniently referenced by all the components.
2. Put `Constants.swift` in the controller. Rationale: Controller is application-specific, and so is `Constants.swift`. Model and View are generic and hence should not be used to store constants.

But I don't know which of the two above I should use, or if there are any better options. What do you all think?

Comment: It really depends on what type of constants they are and what you're using them for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate the constants in the classes that have to do with them and access them like:

```
Configurations.Constants.width or Car.Constant.speed
```

You can use structs with static properties to store them.

Don't know if that is your case, and depends on the constants, but it is not common to have one file with ALL the constants of the program, or one file with constants that need to be accessed from all the other components, this could indicate a design problem. If you store them close to or in the classes related to them, you won't have a problem with Cocoa's MVC.

Comment: This just makes constant access awkwardly verbose. Global constants don't need to be part of a class, and class constants don't need to advertise the fact that they're constant.

Comment: It doesn't need to be called Constants, but still, if you want to group them in a struct and make them static, I don't know what is the problem with that. And the question asks about how using constants with MVC. There is no problem about constants being in the Model like he was saying, it really depends on the which constants are. Anyway it is not common to have a file with all the constants.